# Use the definition of partial derivative to show that ∂f/ ∂x (0, 0) does not exist

Tags: partial-derivative, vector-analysis

[I just need help with part b of this problem][1]

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$.

a) Show that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

b) Use the definition of partial derivative to show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exist.

Comment: $f(x,0)-f(0,0)=2$. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You just have to setup the proposed limit $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2-0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2}{h}.$$What about lateral limits?

Comment: I don't understand how you got 2....
and what are lateral limits?

Comment: I just plugged in $x = h$ and $y = 0$ in the expression for $f(x,y)$. And [lateral limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) you should have learned in single variable calculus (it's a terrible idea to tackle multivariable calculus before that).

Comment: Okay, yes I am familiar with one-sided limits. I've just never heard them be referred to as "lateral limits"

Comment: Okay, so you get 2/h. Take the limit as h approaches zero from above (0+) and you get positive infinity. Take the limit as h approaches zero from below (0-) and you get negative infinity. Since you get different values for the limit, the partial at (0,0) DNE.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely!